# Android get image Uri from camera, store in SQLite and restore it on my custom adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, camera, datatableadapters

I followed the Android developers example of get an image form the camera intent and place it on your view. The problem starts when I try to save that image uri on my `SqliteDatabase` ( just the link to that image not the full image so I save space) and then I try to restore it on my customadapter.

Link to google dev - > http://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html

I tried this without success

created a global string logo, and inside `handleSmallCameraPhoto` put this

```
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ImagenViaje.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        ImagenViaje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    --> logo = extras.get("data").toString();
```

Then I stored logo on SQLite, and tried to restore it on my adapter this way

```
String imagePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LOGO_PATH));
```

Then

```
 ImageView item_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    item_image.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

        item_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        item_image.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

get path of image using

```
Uri selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
String s1 = intent.getDataString(); 

String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
if(selectedImagePath==null && s1 != null)
{
    selectedImagePath = s1.replaceAll("file://","");
}
```

in your `handleSmallCameraPhoto` method

add this method in your activity

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

    try{
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor==null)
    {
        return null;

    }
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

save `selectedImagePath` in your database and use when you need `selectedImagePath` is path of your selected image

hope help you..

Comment: Dont works, when I put in handleSmallCameraPhoto a test Toast - > Toast.makeText(this, selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); alw shows blank, so looks liek its not getting the URI, and its storing in sql a blank field :(